Is there licence issue forking ubuntu where 'likeness' comes into play?
Reason I'm asking is because the name I would want to use is bubuntu cuz I am weird like that and been calling ubuntu: bubuntu for a few years just cuz.  The technical reason I had to ask this is because does the likeness of "bubuntu" vs "ubuntu" cause any issue?  Or can I make a cool meme bubuntu distro for fast cloud spins  (with good intentions)?  One day, and if so I'd hope to be cool kid with that new bubuntu ;)  Like ubuntu with turbos :D
